# One JVM has one instrumentation?

Tags: java, instrumentation

Question is simple.

We can attach many agent in a jvm.

Does each agent get different instrumentation instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One JVM has one set of instrumentation. I'm not certain that you can attach multiple agent instances, but I am certain that they would be "debugging" the same instructions with the same threads and the same instances (again, if they're instrumenting the same JVM).